# Synonym for a vehicle "making its way"

Tags: synonyms

What (preferably single-word) verb could I use instead of *making their way* in sentence below?

> Vehicles making their way through the streets

If I was talking about people, I could say *"People **walking down** the streets"* instead of **making their way**, but that wouldn't work for cars and other vehicles.

Does "Vehicles **moving** through streets" sounds good?

Thanks!

Comment: What would you want to imply by that sentence? I mean you can say from "there are cars on the streets" to "the cars on streets moving in opposite directions on the two-lane roads". So, the context would be very important. Side note: the example you provided is not a sentence.

Comment: "Moving through" isn't a single word, quite, but it's appropriate. "Wending their way" is another idiom you could look up.  Any of the words along, down, or through includes the idea of moving, so you can choose a verb to emphasize some other aspect of the motion. For vehicles, "rolling along" could fit. If the vehicles are moving fast, "speeding along". Or "roaring down", if you want to emphasize the noise.

Comment: "moving through", "passing through", "cruising"

Answer (score 1):

From the helicopter he could see ...

... vehicles making their way along the streets

... vehicles driving along the streets

... vehicles moving along the streets

... vehicles threading their way though the narrow streets

... vehicles passing along the crowded streets

etc.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cars+were+travelling%2C+cars+were+moving%2C+cars+were+driving+&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccars%20were%20travelling%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccars%20were%20moving%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccars%20were%20driving%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 0):

"Driving" is probably the most natural.

Otherwise you could use any number of words, depending on the atmosphere you want to create. For example:

- hurtling
- heading
- cruising
- meandering

This is by no means an exhaustive list.

Comment: Thanks! I thought *driving* usage was limited to refer to *people* controlling the car (like *"people driving around the streets"*), not the car itself as well (*"cars driving around the streets"*). Just checked the dictionary - you're right.